# Quel prénom français serait équivalent au latin "gajus"?

Tags: latin

Le prénom "Gajus" (ou "Gaius", "Cajus", "Caius") est très répandu en latin, quel est le prénom français équivalent?

Par exemple, Augustus a donné Auguste, Octavianus a donné Octavien, etc.

Comment: Seul *Caius* semble avoir survécu au siècle dernier : https://www.magicmaman.com/prenom/caius,2006200,1695064.asp … mais ce prénom n'a pas survécu au troisième millénaire. *Cais* est peut-être un dérivé ?

Comment: Le prénom français dérivé de Gaïa est Caius. Caius est un prénom qui apparaît dans l'Hexagone en 1925. Ce prénom fait donc partie des prénoms anciens de France. C'est un prénom que très peu de garçons portent. Ils sont en effet 3 depuis 1925 à s'appeler ainsi. Ce renseigement est quand même [très facile à trouver.](https://www.parents.fr/prenoms/caius-36977#Etymologie-du-pr%C3%A9nom-Caius)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beaucoup de prénoms romains en *-us* comme *Claudius*, *Petrus*, *Julius*, *Marcus*, *Lucius*, *Tiberius* ont vu leur forme francisée : *Claude*, *Pierre*, *Jules*, *Marc*, *Luc*, *Tibère*.

Certains autres, comme *Marius*, *Darius*, *Titus* et *Cassius* semblent n'avoir été portés qu'avec cette terminaison.

On trouve une francisation du prénom Caïus mais semble-t-il uniquement pour faire référence au [Pape Caïus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ca%C3%AFus_(pape)) nommé alors ***Caïe*** ou ***Caië*** :

(Source: Jacqueline Bouette de Blémur, *Vie des saints, tirée des auteurs ecclésiastiques anciens*, 1689) :

[image]

En France, on trouve ce prénom écrit **Cajus**, dans un manuscrit de 1600 sur Caïus de Virailh né en 1522 à Sisteron ([BNF](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b100158623/f7.double)) :

[image]

La plupart des autres sources écrivent ce prénom soit ***Caius*** soit surtout ***Caïus***.

Ex (Généanet):

[image]

On peut trouver des occurrences de ce prénom peu populaire jusqu'au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle mais il n'y a plus eu de naissance d'un Caïus  en France depuis 1948. Le dernier porteur du prénom est mort en 2017 à 92 ans.

Entre 1896 et 1948, il y a eu dix naissances de Caïus. Quatre ont eu lieu en France métropolitaine (la dernière en 1907), les six autres à la Réunion.